# trouble regarding inserting values in database using android

Tags: android, sql, database, insert

When click on submit button shows an error.

database.java

```
package k.l;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class database extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    public static final String dbname="mydb.db";
    public static final String dtab="mytution";
    public static final String name="name";
    public static final String passwrd="passwrd";
    public static final String address="address";
    public static final String email="email";
    public static final String phone="phone";
    public static final int dver=5;

    public database(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
            int version) {
        super(context,dbname, factory, 5);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String str="create table mytution(name text not null,passwrd text not null,address text,email text not null,phone text);";
        db.execSQL(str);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Login.java

```
package k.l;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class login extends Activity{
    EditText name,addr,phn,pswd,emailid;
    Button submit;
    database db1=new database(this, "mydb.db", null, 5);

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        addr=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.address);
        phn=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.phn);
        pswd=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        emailid=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.signin);




submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            add();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Succefully Registered!", 1000).show();


        }
    });

}
    public void add(){
        SQLiteDatabase sqldb=db1.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put(database.name, name.getText().toString());
        cv.put(database.passwrd, pswd.getText().toString());
        cv.put(database.phone, phn.getText().toString());
        cv.put(database.email, emailid.getText().toString());
        cv.put(database.address, addr.getText().toString());
        sqldb.insert(database.dtab,null, cv);
    }
    }
```

login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/page2">

    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
         android:textColor="#9A32CD"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>



      <EditText
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"   />

     </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Password"
        android:textColor="#9A32CD"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

<EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:id="@+id/password"
    />

     </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Email ID"
        android:textColor="#9A32CD"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

     </LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Phone No"
        android:textColor="#9A32CD"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:inputType="number" />
</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Address"
        android:textColor="#9A32CD"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/address"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPostalAddress" />

     </LinearLayout>
 <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        />
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/signin"
    android:text="Create my account"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#8B475D"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Error - 
07-15 14:26:08.071: I/Database(323): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = table mytution has no column named passwrd

Comment: have u added metadata in db?

Comment: what metadata i did't get u?

Comment: @StefanBeike: its passwrd

Comment: use sqlitemanager to view the table you have created, hope u get your mistake.

Comment: Code looks pretty good to me. Did you add the passwrd field after you tested first? If the database exists, the onCreate method isn't run any more...

Comment: In your edit text did u enter any value for the password field then pressed enter?

Comment: @And.Dev: the entries are not inserting in the database. First it should work for insertion then only i can check to view the table.

Comment: @MichaelSchmidt: i have added passwrd field first time when i created the database.. it's not added later.

Comment: @Abhilash: Yes to submit the full registration form, i have enter the value in password field.

Comment: @Bani by using that you can easily check your table structure and raw table. and try it again by uninstalling the app first. this will delete any previous table.

Comment: The error msg suggests that your table isn't created properly. Try And.Dev's suggestion. Check if the database table is created properly and all columns are there.

Comment: @And.Dev I don't know how to use Sqlitemanager to check the database table. Can u plz write the code or steps, how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Steps for checking database using ddms and sqlite manager

1. First install the [Sqlite Manager](http://portableapps.com/apps/development/sqliteman-portable).
2. Open ddms in file explorer tab go to data inside data select data.
3. Navigate to the folder named as your project name inside that folder goto database and
   select your database file.
4. Pull that file and save to your computer.
5. Open the SqliteManager and open the same file in sqlite manager and then check your table structure.